# how to use TypedDict across files?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, typeddict

I'm a typescript refugee and trying to get python's typechecking to be useful...

I have a TypedDict as below:

```
# definition
class BaseConfig(TypedDict):
    debug: bool
    gcp_project: str
    table_id: str

# example
testConfig: BaseConfig = {
    'debug': True,
    'gcp_project': 'something',
    'table_id': 'some_table',
    'foo': 'bar' # should fail
}
```

now when these are in the same file, all works well.

```
mypy config/base_config.py 
config/base_config.py:18: error: Extra key "foo" for TypedDict "BaseConfig"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

BUT when I move the `testConfig` to another file

and add `from config.base_config import BaseConfig`

I get NO typing errors. I can add random stuff and delete stuff NO PROBLEM!

```
mypy config/testConfig.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

What am I doing wrong? I assume we can have typing across two different files in 2021?

mypy.ini =>

```
# Global options:

[mypy]
python_version = 3.9
check_untyped_defs = True
ignore_missing_imports = True
exclude = 'venv/'

; warn_return_any = True
; warn_unused_configs = True
```

Comment: I also thought of using @dataclass decorator for this stuff but that can't implement required fields. basically I want something like interfaces.

Comment: maybe the directive `ignore_missing_imports` is suppressing a relevant error. Can you remove it and try again?

Comment: yes this helped me find the issue! I didn't have a `__init__` in my configs directory. Always forget that!  Now I get warnings about a bazillion missing imports so I guess it's either too much noise or a broken type checker. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports seem to not override when imported...